# can't authenticate to kubectl to access aws eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubectl

I'm trying to access AWS EKS pods using kubectl.

Steps I've taken:

1. Installed awscli
2. Confirmed 'myprofile' user has IAM EKS admin permissions
3. Run `awscli configure --profile myprofile`
4. Installed aws-iam-authenticator
5. Confirmed user access with `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile myprofile`
6. Set the EKS access configuration: `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name mynode --profile myprofile`
7. when I run cat `~/.kube/config` I can see the correct cluster, user, arn, certificate-authority-data, etc.

Yet when I run `kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth`, `kubectl get roles -A`, or `kubectl get nodes` (per [AWS's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)) I still get:

```
E0814 14:12:38.261260   96693 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

I also cannot retrieve the current config map for the same reason (`kubectl get configmap aws-auth -n kube-system -o yaml`). How can I debug this further? thanks

Comment: how did you create the cluster, using which user ??

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I found the reason I lost access was because a nodegroup associated with the EKS cluster was mistakenly deleted. Once I restored that, I then used the --profile that created the cluster to authenticate:

1. `awscli configure --profile cluster-creator-user`
2. `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile cluster-creator-user`
3. `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster --profile cluster-creator-user`